# Obtain all changes from database change tracking

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, change-tracking

I know how to get changes from one table but what I want is to get the changes from all the tables. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: Redgate SQL Compare allows you to compare two databases and see all the changes (there are data and structure comparers). It isn't free but there is a 14-day trial

Comment: For data. I didn't try anything because I couldn't find anything on Google. I only know how to do it for one table only.

Comment: Show your code please and I'll try to help you

Comment: I'm really sorry for the misunderstanding. I accidentally added the C# tag. I don't want C# code, but just a SQL script.

Comment: @GauriK. Okay, look at my SQL answer.

Comment: @GauriK. Please send your SQL code.

Answer (score 0):

In order to make your diff operation per table in your you can *list* all of them using SQL, look:

```
USE YourDBName
GO 
SELECT *
FROM sys.Tables
GO
```

Comment: This is what I have so far:
    declare synchronization_version bigint
SET synchronization_version = CHANGE_TRACKING_CURRENT_VERSION();
select * from changetable(changes layouts, synchronization_version )as ct

Comment: @GauriK. What do you what to achieve? Do you want to compare your DB tables against other DB tables?

Comment: No, I want to see what data is changed